# How to get Desktop and Mobile menu not reset the index when switching in between screens?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, responsive-design, flutter-layout

I have a main Widget called HomePage and two other widgets corresponding to the Desktop and Mobile version of the site. Each of them has a menu. I want to be able to resize my window and not have the menu index reset.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a `ValueNotifier<int> menuIndex = ValueNotifier(0)` and then wrapping both Desktop and Mobile menus with a `ValueListenerBuilder`.